# PHP - sorting multidimensional array using array_multisort

Tags: php, array-multisort

I have this multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [at] => 3
            [bt] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 3
        )

)
```

I want to sort it by key "at" so I tried this code

```
//$process = array() given above

$p = array();

foreach ($process as $key => $row) {
        $p[$key] = $row['at'];
}

array_multisort($p, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC, $process);
```

and I get this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [at] => 3
            [bt] => 5
        )

)
```

It sorts the "at" BUT it also sorts "bt".

How can I sort this array on key "at" ONLY?

Like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [at] => 3
            [bt] => 5
        )

)
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

As for the answer below by callmemath

When I only have this on my array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [at] => 0
            [bt] => 3
        )
)
```

How can I prevent it from sorting since I only want to sort it by key "at". And nothing to sort there since they are both 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) :

```
$array = array(
            array('at' => 0, 'bt' => 9),
            array('at' => 3, 'bt' => 5),
            array('at' => 0, 'bt' => 3)
        );

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['at'] - $b['at'];
});

var_dump($array);
```

[Try it on Php online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c24f5a674a144c085d36682e9617014d6b3d4918)

Comment: I edited the question. I just thought it only happens if I only have 2 elements in my `$process` array. So I create a condition in callback function. Thanks again.